# Using github for a very large website

Tags: git, version-control, github

I'm a bit of a novice with Git so I'm hoping someone can help here. I am new to a project that has been going on for quite some time using Git. It's a HUGE website with thousands upon thousands of images, pdfs, etc. The files for this website have been ignored using gitignore. These files however are required for the website to run. I'm able to manually download and add them to the current branch I'm working on and the website runs. However, when I switch branches, I lose all the files. As far as I know, this is the expected behavior of Git. However, do I have to manually add these files every time I switch to a different branch that hasn't had these files added yet?

I hope this question makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be adding them to the repo at all.

Comment: There is a reason why those images and the pdfs weren't part of  repo - You can't track changes to them, the diffs would be absolutely absurd, and the combined file size (for 1000s of files) will bloat your repository to insane proportions. I would suggest discarding commits for these images, there is no way any sane user will accept your code merges containing images and pdfs.

Comment: I thought that by adding them to gitignore they are not part of the repo. I'm I'm right, then this is what I'm asking. Every time I switch branches I need to add these required files because they are not part of the repo.

Answer (score 2):

This may be off the track.  But wouldn't it make more sense to host the static content separately from the source code?  Not only does this make development a lot easier -- you can focus on code instead of missing images, but also makes deployment a breeze.  And from the user's perspective, this usually means improved performance. For one, the web app does not need to handle that many requests for images any more.  Secondly, the image host can be specially optimized with CDN to delivery such staff more efficiently.  Thirdly, images not part of the deploy will be more likely cached on the client side.

Comment: I think I'm confused here. I'm working on a local server using XAMPP and I've cloned the project to my htdocs folder. I switch to a branch I'm working on but need to ADD the required images and other files for the website to work. These required files and images are set to be ignored however when I switch branches these files disappear and I need to add them again. This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I would guess that the project is by default set up to have a `images` folder as part of the source code. Then an image on a web page may be referenced something like this `<img src="/images/image1.png">`.

Instead of doing that, you can upload the images to an image server and get rid of the image folder from the source code. Then the same web page would refer to the image like this `<img src="http://myimage.host.com/image1.png" />`

Comment: You can even dynamically write the image host to be the local host just for development. You can then store the images locally but they are never part of source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ignoring the folder, I think it shouldn't go away. Make sure you do a `git rm -r --cached .` in the root and then `git add .`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to solve the symptom of a problem rather than the problem itself. I would personally put all the images in a git submodule.

See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80962/should-images-be-stored-in-a-git-repository for more suggestions.